# Angular JS: Child Components Rendered in First Column Instead of Corresponding Columns in Parent Component Table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'm working on an Angular application where I have a parent component (HomeComponent) that renders a table with child components (TableEntriesComponent) in each row. However, I'm facing an issue where all child components are rendering in the first column instead of corresponding columns.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

**HomeComponent:**

**HTML**

```
<h1>
 Home Page
</h1>
<div id="HomeDiv">
    <form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" required >

        <br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>

        <br>

        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message"  [(ngModel)]="message" name="message" rows="4" required></textarea>

        <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="OnSubmit()">
    </form>
    </div>
      <table Id="HomeTable" *ngIf=Issubmitted>
         <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
       </tr>
<tr *ngFor="let Msg of Messages; let Index=index">
<app-table-entries
        [Index]="Index"
        [Name]="Msg.Name"
        [Email]="Msg.Email"
        [Message]="Msg.Message"
        (onDelete)="onDelete($event)"
      >
</app-table-entries>      
</tr>
</table>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConstantPool } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


name:string='';
email:string='';
message:string='';
Issubmitted:boolean=false;
Messages:Array<any>=[];
 onDelete(index: number): void {
    // Handle the deletion logic for the specified index
    this.Messages.splice(index, 1);
  }
  OnSubmit():void
    {
    this.Issubmitted=true;
    this.Messages.push(
    {
      'Name':this.name,
      'Email':this.email,
      'Message':this.message
    });
    } 
   

constructor() {
  
  
 }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

}
```

**CSS**

```
   body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        form {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
        }

        input,
        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background-color: #4caf50;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
#SubmittedValue
{
  background-color: lightcoral;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10pt;
  margin: 10pt;
  border-radius: 20pt;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold
}

 table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
```

**ChildComponent:**

**HTML**

```
<td>{{Index+1}}</td>
<td>{{Name}}</td>
<td>{{Email}}</td>
<td>{{Message}}</td>
<td><button (click)="handleDelete()">Del</button></td>
```

**Typescript**

```
import {Input, Output, Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-entries',
  templateUrl: './table-entries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-entries.component.css']
})
export class TableEntriesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Index: number;
  @Input() Name: string;
  @Input() Email: string;
  @Input() Message: string;
  @Output() onDelete: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
  
  handleDelete(): void {
    this.onDelete.emit(this.Index);
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In the parent component's HTML, I have a table with child components in each row. However, all child components are rendering in the first column. I expected each child component to be in its corresponding column.

Could you please review my code and suggest what might be causing this issue? Am I missing something in the template or the component logic?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**OUTPUT CURRENTLY COMING**

[image]

**Expected OUTPUT are below**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is not recognize as a tr.
One option is to use the attribute selector `[]`.

Try it like:

```
<table Id="HomeTable" *ngIf=Issubmitted>
        <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
       </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody *ngFor="let Msg of Messages; let Index=index">
           
            <tr app-table-entries
        [Index]="Index"
        [Name]="Msg.Name"
        [Email]="Msg.Email"
        [Message]="Msg.Message"
        (onDelete)="onDelete($event)"
       >
      </tr>    
       </tbody>
</table>
```

And in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-table-entries]',
  templateUrl: './table-entries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-entries.component.css']
})
```

Comment: That also added now but still it is appears in the same first column. You can also refer ng-now link for preview of this code. https://ng-run.com/edit/AA2VSd9jOPdBeehDNmlX

Comment: @NachiappanR updated my answer, thanks for the rg-run-example

Comment: Its working like a charm, thanks for the your swift response and answer :-)